# iPad 6th gen not charging

Tags: ipad

I have an ipad 6th gen that I bought almost 5 years ago. The battery probably lasts 2-3 hours on normal use. It ran out of battery yesterday, and I've been trying to charge it all day, and it doesn't seem to be charging. When I press the home button, it shows the "low battery symbol" indicating that it's charging, but it seems to never turn on.

Presumably, the battery is fried, but given that it was lasting 2-3 hours for a full charge, it seems strange that it would all of a sudden stop working like this? Are there any troubleshooting steps I can take in this case?

And yes, I've tried different charging cables.

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store, where they can confirm the state of the battery, and offer you a replacement battery. (Some models, they replace the whole thing, but still just charge the battery rate.)

Comment: @benwiggy will do. this model is worth like $130 for a refurbished one. it's probably not worth paying for a battery replacement at this point, though idk how much apple would change but I imagine it's around $100

Comment: Have you tried these: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102612. And yep, I just tried Apple's "Get an estimate" tool, it says $99 for battery servicing.

Comment: @Thinkr I haven't, but I was able to get it to charge today. Idk what happened, but now it works, and I was able to charge it to 100%. Making sure I back everything up in case it gets fried again :)

Comment: @roulette01 Oh? Well, nice for you. Might still be useful to find the issue so you could be able to fix it next time it happens ;)